# Importing Python Library Inside QGIS Plugin for all OS using Subprocess

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, subprocess

I am writing a QGIS python plugin which needs pandas library to function. I have searched the GIS.SE and there are many similar questions but none talks about using subprocess and that if it will work on all OS. People have suggested using pip.main() but the pip.main() has been deprecated. I have developed the following method of importing/installing pandas.

I need to know if this will work on all OS. I am on Windows and this works fine on windows.

```
try:
    try:
        import pandas as pd
    except ImportError:
        import pathlib as pl
        import subprocess
        import sys

        qgis_Path = pl.Path(sys.executable)
        qgis_python_path = (qgis_Path.parent / "python3.exe").as_posix()

        subprocess.check_call(
            [qgis_python_path, "-m", "pip", "install", "--user", "pandas"]
        )
        import pandas as pd

        feedback.pushInfo(
            "python library pandas was installed for qgis python"
        )
except:
    feedback.reportError(
        "Failed to import pandas. Tried installing pandas but failed.\nPlease manually install pandas for the python that comes with your QGIS or run this algorithm with Skip Output option for Report as HTML."
)
```

Comment: `pip.main() has been deprecated` Maybe but there is always a hidden function to do the same e.g `from pip._internal import main` then `main(['install', 'pandas'])`

Comment: @ThomasG77 you are correct but there is a reason why it has been deprecated and has been explained in the docs. Since this is not the correct way to do it, I want to avoid using pip.main() especially if the subprocess will work fine on all OS.